# Replace content of a card on row click with slide in animation

Tags: javascript, replace, html-table, onclick

Here is my codepen:
https://codepen.io/liamdthompson/pen/YJyaor

```
<div class="card contactcard">
 <table class="table table-borderless table-hover">                               
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <th  scope="row"  >1</th>
       <td>Mark Jones</td>
       <td>Yesterday, 6:40 pm</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <th  scope="row" >2</th>
       <td>Mark Jones</td>
       <td>Yesterday, 6:40 pm</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <th  scope="row" >3</th>
       <td>Mark Jones</td>
       <td>Yesterday, 6:40 pm</td>
     </tr>

    </tbody>
   </table>
```

It is a bootstrap table inside a card. That shows contact form submissions. The view pulls the name and the date of submission, but I'd like it that the rest of the submission content is revealed on click.

I would like it so that when a user clicks on a row, the table disappears and users can see a blank card that contains the rest of the form submission. Hopefully, this can be accompanied by a slide in animation that looks like it's 'pushing' the table out of the way from right to left. Hopefully this makes sense!

Comment: Use javascript addEventListener method, table.addEventListener('click', function() { /* do stuff here*/ }, false);

Comment: what would the do stuff here be?